# Difference between `nx affected:lint --fix` and `nx format:write`

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

What is the difference between `nx affected:lint --fix` and `nx format:write`?

Different articles does seem to mention that code should be formatted with `nx format:write` command, but it doesn't seem that it fully relies on ESLint rules.

After formatting I keep having ESLint errors.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

so `nx format:write` does the code formatting using the prettier config which is in the root of the project.

`nx affected:lint --fix` instead fixes linting problems.

Comment: only one pity problem is that these 2 commands are unable not to lint/format unstaged files. They are basically "all or nothing"